# Get original text inside visitor

Tags: python, antlr4, visitor-pattern

I try to get original input text inside the visitor
I use the python target with this code

```
txt = ctx.start.getInputStream().getText(ctx.start.tokenIndex, ctx.stop.tokenIndex)
```

it returns the original text well but the indexes returned are not good.

someone knows why?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are using token indices to get a char range. Instead use `ctx.start.startIndex` and `ctx.stop.stopIndex`.

**Note:** The python runtime deviates here from the other runtimes by naming these members `start` and [`stop`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Python3/src/antlr4/Token.py#L39) instead (and uses properties instead of access functions):

```py
txt = ctx.start.getInputStream().getText(ctx.start.start, ctx.stop.stop)
```